# Burninate the [gnu] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The excerpt for [gnu](/questions/tagged/gnu) reads:

> This tag is for programming questions related to software and tools
>   provided by the GNU ("GNU's Not Unix") project.

I feel that this is too broad and if the tag were to be applied as per the excerpt, it might very well cover not only most of Linux/*nix questions, but also questions pertaining to [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc), [emacs](/questions/tagged/emacs), and a host of [other utilities](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/GNU).

Having a tag this broad doesn't seem to serve much purpose.

Comment: A similar argument can probably be made for [tag:windows] and [tag:linux], though I do see a purpose to them - e.g. a programming question related to getting the version of Windows you're running. Whether or not a similar argument applies to GNU - my guess is that it does. Perhaps the excerpt should just be changed.

Comment: I've seen far worse tags.

Comment: How frequently is the tag used? Do folk find it useful?